# How to include another project libraries and few another .NET libraries in the single file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a single file application, with this command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --framework net5.0-windows -p:PublishReadyToRun=true --self-contained true /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

It reduces de number of files so much, and my exe file contains most of the files, because the size is about 166MB, but not all the files are includes. For example, the dll from another proeject that I am using are not included, and another files like Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll, clrcompression.dll and another few more, in total 27 files, are not included.

I would like to know if it is really possible to create a single file with all the files that it is needed to run the application, dll from my others projects and the rest of files of .NET libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to include unmanaged dlls, and at least some of the SQL support libraries are unmanaged.

Comment: Try to set `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` or `IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract` properties, as mentioned in [design document](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md#optional-settings)